# double free or corruption (out) seg fault in c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting an error `double free or corruption (out)` when the thread below exits. I believe it is related to my use of `malloc()` and calling `free()` at the end. I can't understand what is wrong with what I am doing.

Would anybody know why this is happening or could point me in the right direction?

```
 static void *serial_logging_dut1_thread(prv_thread_params_t *threadParams) {

    ssize_t rdlen = 0;
    int res_port, res_file, res_close;
    char ibuf[1024];


    char *filename_ending = "_dut1_serial_log.txt";
    char *filename_with_extension;
    prv_instance_t *targetP = threadParams->targetP;

    /*append filename ending "_dut1_serial_log.txt" to the power data filename supplied in the experiment script*/
    filename_with_extension = malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename)+1+20);
    strcpy(filename_with_extension, targetP->output_filename); /* copy name into the new var */
    strcat(filename_with_extension, filename_ending); /* add the extension */

    LOG("Started thread for serial logging from DUT 1\r\n");

    /*Open log file and write to it from /dev/USB1*/
    res_file = create_open_log_file(filename_with_extension);

    if (res_file) {
        LOG("Error creating the serial log file");
        serial_logging_res = -1;
        pthread_exit(&serial_logging_res);
    }

    res_port = log_dut_serial_data(joule_serial_port);

    if (res_port) {
        LOG_ARG("Error opening the serial port to DUT 1, check the cable %s\n",joule_serial_port);
        serial_logging_res = -2;
        pthread_exit(&serial_logging_res);
    }

    memset(&ibuf[0], 0, sizeof(ibuf)); /*clear the buffer*/

    /*while DUT is turned on and serial port was opened*/
    while (serial_logging_running == 1 && res_port == 0) {
     //do stuff
    }

    /*close file*/
    fclose(log_file);
    res_close = close_serial_port_joule();


    if (res_close) {
            LOG("Error closing the serial port to DUT 1");
        }

    free(filename_with_extension);

    serial_logging_res = 0;
    pthread_exit(&serial_logging_res);

}
```

Including `create_open_log_file()`. I don' think that this is the cause though?

```
int create_open_log_file(char dut1_serial_log_filename[]) {

char filename[256];
sprintf(filename,"/var/log/serial_log/%s", dut1_serial_log_filename);
log_file = fopen(filename,"a");

if (log_file == NULL) {
    LOG("Error creating log file\n");
    return -1;
}
LOG_ARG("Successfully opened the serial logging file %s\n", dut1_serial_log_filename);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I think you double freed, also known as calling free two time on the same memory.
Can you provide the code of create_open_log_file()

Comment: Possibly you put more than allocated into `filename_with_extension` (don't have all the code that deal with that pointer so...)

Comment: Are you sure that you are not freeing memory allocated to `filename_with_extension` in `create_open_log_file()`?

Comment: What `create_open_log_file` is doing? Show it.

Comment: Cannot see where you would do double deletion, but the code shown reveals memory leaks: You do *not* free the string before every `pthread_exit`, so the `fn_w_e` is leaking everywhere but at the last -- *unless* you free it within `create_open_log_file`, as Eugene suspected already...

Comment: I suggest you to verify after `filename_with_extension = malloc(strlen(targetP->output_filename)+1+20);` that the variable is not null. This doesn't solve the issue, but is good practice.

Comment: What happens if you increase the amount of memory you've allocated by a few more bytes?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is due to `free(filename_with_extension);`?

Comment: ` if (res_file) {...}` exits the thread without freeing the memory! (also `if (res_port) {...}`)

Comment: @Sir Jo Black - no I am not 100% sure that it is.

Comment: I think that is not the problem, but is good practice to correctly manage the memory to avoid various kind of issues!

Comment: How much times is the thread spawned with errors!? ... If you spawn the thread thousands (millions) times you may have problems of memory!

Comment: When you release (if you release) the memory related to threadParams you use the pthread_join?